# WordPress plugin causing 503 error on activation on production only

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have a WordPress plugin that when activated on a `production` server causes the pages (only on front-end, not on the `wp-admin` side) to show up as a blank screen and sometimes print a `503 error`. The `console` shows no error output and neither does the `source` show much of anything (besides the 503 error). I don't see anything in the `debug log` either.

On `localhost` with `wampserver` - everything works fine.

What could possibly be going wrong and how do I resolve this?

I am a bit lost at this point since there isn't an error pointing me to where the issue is. Just a blank screen when you activate the plugin.

Comment: Do you have PHP and WordPress error turned on?

Comment: I have errors turned in on wp-config as follows: define('WP_DEBUG', true);
 define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
 define('WP_DEBUG_LOG',     true);
 @ini_set ('display_errors', 0);

Comment: Zero is off, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/231316

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily a fix in terms of figuring out what was wrong - but updating other plugins seemed to resolve some plugin conflict and the plugin is now working.